# c# graphics.RotateTransform vs. graphics.Transform.Rotate

Tags: c#, matrix, graphics, system.drawing

I'm trying to figure out what is going on here:

having a `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Graphics` objects called `g`.

g.Transform has these values:

```
[0] = 1
[1] = 0
[2] = 0
[3] = -1
[4] = 0
[5] = 1122.66663
```

when doing

```
int minAngle = 0;
g.Transform.Rotate(360 - minAngle);
```

I get the same elements for the `g.Transform` property:

```
[0] = 1
[1] = 0
[2] = 0
[3] = -1
[4] = 0
[5] = 1122.66663
```

However when I do:

```
int minAngle = 0;
g.RotateTransform(360 - minAngle);
```

I get these elements for the `g.Transform` property:

```
[0] = 0.99999994
[1] = 3.019916E-07
[2] = 3.019916E-07
[3] = -0.99999994
[4] = 0
[5] = 1122.66663
```

Why is there such a big rounding difference between both methods, which seem to do the same: modifying the world transform?

Besides the floating point rounding 'issue', is there any difference when using rotateTransfrom vs. transform.rotate ?

(.NET Framework 4.8)

Comment: it doesn't explain why both functions behave differently as they do 'the same'...? I know floating point has rounding 'issues' but doesn't explain the difference in both methods.

Comment: How are those differences 'big'?

Comment: big enough to result in a 'Parameter is not valid' when assigning the RotateTransform to a matrix. (doesn't happen with g.Transform.Rotate). So actually breaks existing working code it seems...

Comment: Can you show the code? Most likely it is not too big but too small for some geometric operations. So, yes, you may have to insert checks/corrections..

Comment: I've showed 'the code'. just a graphics object where transform property has the values as said in the post. next just a simple rotatetransform vs. transform.rotate giving different rounding results.

Comment: I meant the code that results to the 'Parameter is not valid' error.

Comment: turns out that code was a small miscalculation resulting in an incorrect transformation. You can ignore that :-) (back again to the differences on why one calculates "correctly" and the other "doesn't")

Comment: _back again to the differences on why one calculates "correctly" and the other "doesn't"_ The quote characters are the answer: In the realm of floating point numbers the perceived difference is moot.